# Can't verify checksum for downloaded LTS 12.04 ISO and can't verify burn either

Tags: 12.04, checksums, hash

I tried to verify my download checksum in mac's disk utility, but it couldn't find a checksum to verify. Also tried to burn ISO at slowest speed and still it couldn't verify the burn.

Any other hints to verify download or get a clean burn?

Comment: ur working on mac right?

Comment: with what are you burning the iso?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to verify an MD5 checksum on a Mac, you need to do this:

Open Terminal

Type `openssl md5 [filename]`

Change ‘md5′ to ‘sha1′ if you want to verify the SHA-1 hash as well.

Comment: Also, with `coreutils` package comes `md5sum`, `sha1sum` and more (224, 256, 384, 512..)

Comment: A method that works (in Ubuntu) to verify cloning to a USB drive is described in [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=62&p=14142910#post14142910) to a post in the Ubuntu Forums.